# userdir public_html Directories

Tags: php, apache2, webserver, debian, lamp

i have been using a vps for learning purposes only.

i have been trying to install a LAMP server in the vps and successfully am able to use /var/www/ to put files and directories and view them on my own external web browser. however, i am now trying to display webpages from users home directory. for example /home/user1/public_html and i am able to successfully view the .php/.html files from that root folder. the problem is, i get a internal server error when trying to access sub directories. for example, /home/user1/public_html/subdir/

http://serveraddress.com/~user1/index.php displays from /home/user1/public_html/index.php

http://serveraddress.com/~user1/subdir/index.php does not displays from /home/user1/public_html/subdir/index.php

http://serveraddress.com/~user1/subdir/index.php displays from /var/www/subdir/index.php

i used both of these tutorials exactly:
https://wiki.debian.org/LaMp
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-debian

i have also looked online but cant seem to pinpoint the error. i have chmod 755 all the way up to /home directory since some sites have said, and chgrp www-data /home//public_html and even made user1:www-data or user1:user1 across the /home/user/public_html/subdir.

again, im just using the vps for learning. any advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post your .htaccess file and any other Apache config you're using?

Comment: i have not touched any .htaccess files and the only changes i have made are what the tutorials in the op say but here are the configs from /etc/apache2/mods-available:

apache2.conf -> https://thisurl.in/UYRiF
userdir.conf -> https://thisurl.in/EQS03
php5.conf -> https://thisurl.in/IKk1O